# Array.length equals 0 always

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get the length of my array, but I always getting 0 even when the console show that I push 5 objets

```
async function getDiaries() {
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  var url = firebase.database().ref('/diary');
  var diaries = [];
  url.on('value', (snap) => {
    snap.forEach((child) => {
        diaries.push({
          key: child.key,
          name: child.val().name,
          date: child.val().description,
          url: child.val().url,
          idOwner: child.val().idOwner
        });
    });
});
console.log(diaries.length);// get 0
resolve(diaries)
})}
```

This is what the console shows me 
[image]

Comment: You are printing before your array gets filled... you are misleading in async concepts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`url.on` is likely asynchronous, meaning you need to do the `console.log` inside the callback:

```
async function getDiaries() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var url = firebase.database().ref('/diary');
    var diaries = [];
    url.on('value', (snap) => {
      snap.forEach((child) => {
        diaries.push({
          key: child.key,
          name: child.val().name,
          date: child.val().description,
          url: child.val().url,
          idOwner: child.val().idOwner
        });
      });
      console.log(diaries.length); // get 0
      resolve(diaries);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! , i'm not a master controlling the asynchronous functions, is hard to get the core idea

Answer (score 1):

Move the console.log into your callback function, otherwise it will mostly always run before your callback is executed. In other words: you get a 0 because the length *is* 0 at this point.

Answer (score 1):

Ofcourse you will get this **0** because this is async function you can try like that

```
async function getDiaries() {
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  var url = firebase.database().ref('/diary');
  var diaries = [];
  url.on('value', (snap) => {
    snap.forEach((child) => {
        diaries.push({
          key: child.key,
          name: child.val().name,
          date: child.val().description,
          url: child.val().url,
          idOwner: child.val().idOwner
        });
    });
    console.log(diaries.length);
    resolve(diaries);
});
})}
```